# Search user with firstname instead of lastname

Tags: active-directory, people-search

When i try to search people in AD or SharePoint, i don't get results on there firstname. I always need to give either fullname or lastname. Is there a way do get John Doe as result for both, "John" and "Doe"?

[image: People Picker]